# Run adb shell commands from Java code on different platforms

Tags: java, android, macos, adb

I am using Mac to run Java program which contains some commands to execute on a remote Android device. When I execute my program on a Windows machine it gives proper output but when I execute the same program on a Mac machine it doesn't. Here I am sharing the code snippet and the output I get.

**Code:**

```
 private static final String DUMPSYSCOMMAND = "adb -s ? shell \"dumpsys package com.PACKAGENAME.service | grep versionName\"";

  String versionString = runADBCommand(DUMPSYSCOMMAND.replace("?",
      deviceIP));
  System.out.println("Version String Result " + versionString);

  String versionName = null;
  if (versionString != null && !versionString.isEmpty()) {
      versionString = versionString.replace("\\s+", "");
      versionName = versionString.replace(".", "-")
          .substring(versionString.indexOf("=") + 1)
          .replaceAll("\\s+", "");
      System.out.println("Version String " + versionName);

  }

public String runADBCommand(String adbCommand) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Running given command= " + adbCommand + "$$$");
        StringBuffer returnValue = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        InputStream inStream = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("adbCommand = " + adbCommand);
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(adbCommand);

            // process.waitFor();/
            inStream = process.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader brCleanUp = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inStream));
            while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.equals("")) {
                    System.out.println("After exec");
                    System.out.println("Line=" + line);

                }

                // returnValue = returnValue + line + "\n";
                returnValue.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            brCleanUp.close();
            try {


                process.waitFor();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(returnValue.toString() + "@@");
        return returnValue.toString();
    }
```

**OutPut:**

```
@@Running given command= adb -s DEVICEIP shell "dumpsys package PACKAGENAME | grep versionName"$$$
adbCommand = adb -s DEVICEIP shell "dumpsys package PACKAGENAME | grep versionName"
After exec
Line=/system/bin/sh: dumpsys package PACKAGENAME | grep versionName: not found
/system/bin/sh: dumpsys package PACKAGENAME | grep versionName: not found
@@Version String Result /system/bin/sh: dumpsys package PACKAGENAME | grep versionName: not found
Version String /system/bin/sh:dumpsyspackagecom-PACKAGENAME|grepversionName:notfound
```

When I run the same shell command from the command prompt it gives me the expected output on Mac as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use `ProcessBuilder` instead. But if you insist on using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` - use `.exec(String[] cmdarray)` instead of your current `.exec(String command)`:

```
private static final String DUMPSYSCOMMAND = "dumpsys package com.PACKAGENAME.service | grep versionName";

String versionString = runADBCommand({"adb", "-s", deviceIP, "shell", DUMPSYSCOMMAND});

...

public String runADBCommand(String[] adbCommand) throws IOException {

...

// do not forget to remove / modify this println - it expect a string
//        System.out.println("adbCommand = " + adbCommand);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!Have tried using process builder and it worked:)

Comment: is there any way to run these command into android application