# ADB PULL Command

Tags: java, android, adb

I am trying to use adb for working with the files in my device from a MAC PC.

One of my folders in my phone has a space in it, so I looked around and tried using escape i.e `\` and also using quotes with as given below

```
import java.io.*;
public class TestModule {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
String line = "null";
String cmd = "adb pull /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/files/test\\ Information/ /Users/sbc/Desktop";
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
System.out.println(line);
}
}
}
```

I ran the same command in terminal I can access the file but through java it gives me remote object does not exist error.

Any help is very much appreciated

Comment: try `String cmd = "adb pull '/storage/sdcard1/Android/data/files/test Information/' /Users/cdp/Desktop";` instead

Comment: or better yet https://stackoverflow.com/q/41764909/1778421

Comment: Hi thankyou for your reply, I tried as you said with single quotes and double quotes, and also as according to the link you suggested, with ProcessBuilder and changing the string to string array. Still I am getting same remote object does not exist error

Comment: also tried giving array list to processBuilder, still no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem, posting code below,

```
import java.io.*;
public class TestModule {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,InterruptedException {

String line = "null";
String cmd = "adb pull /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/files /Users/sbc/Desktop";
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));
while ((line=buf.readLine())!=null) {
System.out.println(line);
}
}
}
```

In place of accessing the folder with the space, I accessed it's parent folder 
/storage/sdcard1/Android/data/files/test\ Information/<--current folder with space
/storage/sdcard1/Android/data/files<--Parent Folder.

Now adb downloads all the contents of "Parent Folder"